# array of pointers to pointers how to initialize the correct and concise way of doing it and using it

Tags: c

I like to know that I have data which are in pair of two strings so there are a list of pair of two strings. like

```
{{"<html","</html>"},{"<head","</head>"}}
```

So I want to define pointer variable as is `array of pointers to pointers` so pointers will be pointing to pointers that points to strings (should be `char *`) like string `<html` is pointed by pointer `*tags_1[0]` and `</html>` is pointed to by what, I may be completely wrong? this is a question. But first I like to know how to define or construct this array of pointers to pointers like initialiing it with above `{{"<html","</html>"},{...}}` for tags_1

I tried like `char **tags_1[2]={{"<html","</html>"},{"<head","</head>"}};` but this obviously wrong but I can do this if I have array of pointers `static char *tags[] = {"<html","<head","<body","<div","<h1","<h2","<h3","<h4","<h5","<br", "<span","<input","<footer","<section","<table","<tr","<td","<a","<button","<end"};`

so my question is how to define like assigning initialized values to array of pointers to pointers then how to use them especially comparing string `<html` and `</html>` indexed elements with `strncmp` of array of pointers to pointers and `printf` and assigning character to each indexed of string (char *). Can anyone please tell me this

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but do you want something like `char ***`?

Comment: That would be a `char *a[][2]` or a `char *a[2][2]`. An array is not a pointer. If you want it to include pointers, you would have to separate some arrays out and then point to those using `&`.

Comment: @kiner_shah I dare say that `***` almost always points to a wrong approach.

Comment: @Cheatah, I am not suggesting at all to use something like that - that's so difficult to manage, but I am just trying to understand if the expected behavior is something like that like 3D array or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A concise way to allocate is to use a *Pointer-to-Array-of* `char*[2]`, e.g.

```c
char *(*tags)[2];
```

That way you can use a single allocation for however many pairs you have, and easily `realloc` if you need more. A short example would be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
  
  char *(*tags)[2] = malloc (2 * sizeof *tags);
  
  tags[0][0] = "<html";
  tags[0][1] = "</html>";
  tags[1][0] = "<head";
  tags[1][1] = "</head>";
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
      printf (" %s", tags[i][j]);
    putchar ('\n');
  }
  
  free (tags);
  
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ptr2arrcharstar
 <html </html>
 <head </head>
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thanks for answer `char *(*tags)[2] = malloc (2 * sizeof *tags);` is this array of pointers to pointers. So does this mean that there is no static initialization for `array of pointers to pointers`? can u please tell

Comment: is it this better to call free for each element?

Comment: @user786 you ask "is this array of pointers to pointers". It's not. As it is stated in this answer, `tags` is a pointer to an array of 2 char-pointers.

Comment: @user786 you ask "is it this better to call free for each element?". You can't `free` individual elements. You can only `free` the whole `tags` in a single call.

Comment: You have a single allocation and a single free. `(*tags)[2]` is a *Pointer-to-Array* of two elements-- without the type being specified. The `(..)` provides the operator precedence. `char *` provides the type. So you have a *Pointer-to-Array-of* `char*[2]`. When you allocate, you allocate for the number of pairs (of *pointers-to* `char`) you need. You are then assigning the address to the string-literals to each of the pointers in your allocated block. If you did not have string-literals, then you would have to allocate storage for each string.

Comment: Another way of saying/thinking about it is a *Pointer-to-Array-of-Two-Pointers-to-char*. Each base unit of allocation is for an array of two pointers (a pair of pointers). So if you `malloc (10 * sizeof *tags)` you allocate 10 rows of 2 columns worth of pointers.

Comment: `(*tags)[2] is a Pointer-to-Array of two elements to char` so if I create pointer to array of three pointers. Then under any circumstances the third element can be function pointer? Any how. The first two pointers to char plus third element is function pointer?

Comment: Yes, but understand, only by virtue of the pointer types being a `char` type. Otherwise you would violate the strict-aliasing rule. If you did `char *(*tags)[3]` then you would have a *Pointer-to-Array-of-Three-Pointers*. You can use the first two pointers as pointers to string-literals, and the third could be a function pointer. However, to make the code more clear/readable, you would want to create a `struct` holding two `char*` pointers and one `void*` pointer. Then you could simply declare `tags` as `struct the_struct *tags;` allocating for an *Array-of-Struct*.

Comment: You could no longer index each literal with 2D array notation (e.g. `tags[0][1]`), but instead you would use member-names, e.g. `tags[0].tag1`, `tags[0].tag2`, and `tag[0].func`. Which you choose will largely depend on how you need to access each. Personally, allocating for a block of `struct` would be cleaner if you wanted pointers to both string-literals and a function pointer -- but both ways are doable.

Comment: @4386427 `You can't free individual elements. You can only free the whole tags in a single call` is this because I allocated from single malloc call?

Comment: Yes. Your `free()` must mirror your allocation. You can only free a block that was previously allocated with `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`. What this means is when you allocate a block of memory, you assign the beginning address for that block to whatever pointer variable you are using. The pointer holds the beginning address to the allocated block as it value. You can only free a block by passing that same address to `free()`. You cannot simply free some random address within the allocated block.

Comment: can u please tell is your code is "pointer" (to) "array of pointers"? and what if I do not want the string literals assigned rather I like to have malloc allocation

Comment: If you want to allocate independently for each string stored, you are free to allocate storage for each pointer and copy any sting you like. You then will be responsible for freeing each allocation. For example `tags[0][0] = malloc (length + 1);` and then `strcpy (tags[0][0], some_string_of_length);` You can still index just as you did when assigning string literals. Also consider simply using a `struct` with two pointers (e.g. `char *tag, *value;`) and then you can simply allocate an array of those -- though you would use member access rather than 2D indexing.

Answer (score 1):

For this you don't need an array of pointers to pointers.

What you need is **an array of array of char-pointers**. It looks like:

```
const char* tags[][2] = {{"<html","</html>"},{"<head","</head>"}};
```

Now you can do stuff like:

```
printf("%s\n", tags[0][0]);  // prints <html
printf("%s\n", tags[1][1]);  // prints </head>
```

and

```
char str[] = "some_text";
if (strcmp(str, tags[1][0]) == 0) // Check if str equals <head
{
    // Match
}
```